# fullcalendar not rendering the events (multiple DateTime lists)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have three lists that I want to be passed through the events (to be shown on the calendar. i.e.

1) WeekDays Dates

2) Present Dates

3) Absent Dates

I'm working on display them on the fullCalendar with `weekDates` being borderlined, `presentDates` being titled "Present" or just a tick mark on the top right most of the cell of the dates and `absentDates` being titled "Absent" or a small cross mark on the top right most of the cell of respective absent dates on the calendar.

Currently, the calendar is shown but not the events (all the desired date lists)

Index.cshtml

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <b>Start Date</b>
            <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" required />
            <b>End Date</b>
            <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" required />
        </div>


        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollNumber, "Enroll ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @style = "float:left; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: 30px;" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EnrollNumber", null, "Select Enroll ID", htmlAttributes: new { id = "ddEnrollNumber", @class = "form-control", @style = "margin-left: -30px; margin-top: 20px;", required = "required", title = "Please select an Enroll ID" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div id="results" name="results"><br /></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn danger" value="Filter" id="getBetween" name="FilterAbsents" onclick="showCal()" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        function showCal() {
            id = $('#EnrollNumber :selected').text();

            s = $("#startDate").val();
            e = $("#endDate").val();

            console.log(s);
            console.log(e);

                $.post("/Absent/showLogs",
                    {
                        EnrollNumber: id,
                        startDate: s,
                        endDate: e
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        callCalendar(response);
                    }
                 );
        }
        function callCalendar(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
            // $('#calendar').html('');

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', e);
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                //defaultDate: '2017-11-13 14:26:36.000',
                //defaultDate: '2017-11-13 09:05 am',
                navLinks: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                events: e,   //or should I change this to > ControllerName/funcName
                slotMinutes:5
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            callCalendar('');
        });
    </script>
}
<style>
    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        ;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
</style>
```

> Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult showLogs(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int EnrollNumber, DateTime? results, FormCollection form)
        {

ICollection<D2L> lstMachineInfo = manipulator.GetD2LData(objZkeeper2, mNum, EnrollNumber).ToList();

// Build list of weekdays
                    List<DateTime> weekDates = new List<DateTime>();
                    int days = (endDate - startDate).Days;
                    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
                    {
                        DateTime date = startDate.AddDays(i);
                        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        weekDates.Add(date);
                    }

                    //at this point I have the weekDays Dates
                    int countWeekDays = weekDates.Count()+1;

                    var mod = (from m in lstMachineInfo
                              where m.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber &&  m.Date >= startDate && m.Date <= endDate
                              select m).Distinct();
                   var presentDates = mod
                    .GroupBy(dt => dt.Date)
                    .Select(z => z.OrderBy(y => y.Date).First())
                    .ToList();
                    // Get the dates to be excluded
                    IEnumerable<DateTime> excluded = presentDates.Select(x => x.Date.Value);
                    // Get the absent dates
                    IEnumerable<DateTime> absentDates = weekDates.Except(excluded);

                    ViewBag.absentDates = absentDates;
                   //instead of just presentDates, I want to pass absentDates and weekDates
                   //and show them on the calendar
                     return Json(presentDates.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Instead of passing `weekDates`, if we can somehow borderline all the weekdays in the calendar using its 'options' then no need to pass the `weekDates`. Only the `presentDates` and the `absentDates` will work!

With the current Code, I get the output in the console as;

```
0: "/Date(1509476400000)/"
1: "/Date(1509562800000)/"
2: "/Date(1509649200000)/"
3: "/Date(1509908400000)/"
4: "/Date(1509994800000)/"
5: "/Date(1510081200000)/"
6: "/Date(1510513200000)/"
7: "/Date(1510858800000)/"
8: "/Date(1511118000000)/"
length: 9
```

**UPDATED:**

So I have been able to display the absentDates and the presentDates but only one list at a time (through code). How do I display both together now;

The following code displays all the presentDates on the calendar;

```
var presentEventList = from e in presentDates
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                id = EnrollNumber,
                                                title = "Present",
                                                start = ((DateTime)e.Date).ToString("s"),
                                                end = ((DateTime)e.Date).ToString("s"),
                                                someKey = e.RegisterationId,
                                                allDay = false
                                            };
                    var presentRows = presentEventList.ToArray();
return Json(presentRows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

However, when I replace the above code with this one, it displays all the absentDates on the calendar.

```
var absentEventList = from e in absentDates
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        id = EnrollNumber,
                                        title = "Absent",
                                        start = ((DateTime)e.Date).ToString("s"),
                                        end = ((DateTime)e.Date).ToString("s"),
                                        someKey = EnrollNumber,
                                        allDay = false
                                    };
                    var absentRows = absentEventList.ToArray();

                    return Json(absentRows,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How do I pass both the list together now? and further more, is there a way to show a tick mark on the presentDates except of the title "Present" and cross mark instead of "Absent" title on the absentDates.

What I tried: 1) Using multiple EventSources like this, but it does not call the showAbsentLogs function.

```
 eventSources: [
// your event source
{
    url: 'Absent/showLogs', // use the `url` property
    color: 'green',    // an option!
    textColor: 'white'  // an option!
},
{ 
    url: 'Absent/showAbsentLogs', // use the `url` property
    color: 'red',    // an option!
    textColor: 'white'  // an option!

}
]
```

A better solution would be to combine both the lists in C#.

Comment: 1) your output isn't in the "event" format as required by fullCalendar. Earlier today on another question I told you to read the docs to see the format required, seem like you still haven't done that? 2) Those are nasty date formats usually output by older versions of ASP.NET. Luckily you can use momentJS to parse them into a momentJS object which fullCalenar can understand. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/. I suggest you do this during the eventDataTransform callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/).

Comment: Alternatively, you could get your C# to output the dates directly as an ISO string which can be parsed natively by fullCalendar. It's cleaner on the client-side but just requires the server-side model to be tweaked a bit (which it needs anyway).

Comment: P.S. your comment in code: `events: e,   //or should I change this to > ControllerName/funcName` . Yes ideally you would do this, as it's more dynamic. Your server-side method has to comply with the description given here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ . fullCalendar will handle passing the start/end dates in (as per the current calendar view). You could add the other parameters using the `data:` option as shown in that article.

Comment: @ADyson  `your output isn't in the "event" format as required by fullCalendar` how should it be then? I knew it had something to do with the date parsing using momentJS but apart from that I need to know how to pass those two lists `presentDates` and `absentDates` to the calendar. An answer with the solution to this problem would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: "How should it be then?". Good grief. For the 100th time **Read the documentation**. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/. Plus see all the hundreds of previous answers on the fullCalendar tag which show actual examples of event data.

Comment: for the two lists, either combine them into one in C#, or use two separate event sources with separate server methods to return the data (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/). You don't need me to spoon-feed you a solution where it seems quite likely that you won't understand half the code, you need to start reading, finding out what's possible and trying stuff for yourself, because all the answers are out there already if you actually try and look.

Comment: @ADyson As stated earlier, I have gone through a lot of previous answers related to the fullCalendar, furthermore. I have read some of the documents too. If this is all you can help, thank you. I shall keep trying :)

Comment: You're asking for quite a bit of stuff compared to the usual content of a SO answer and I don't personally have time to write, test and explain the whole code and process right now. Hence quick comments instead which may be of some help. If that situation changes then I may write something more detailed. IMO if you have already looked through documentation and materials and still don't know how to create an event object then you haven't looked very hard, but there we are.

Comment: @ADyson No worries at all, if you get some time off to explain and answer it'll be one heck of a help!

Comment: @ADyson a little help in concatenating the two lists in c# below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by concatenating both the lists like this;

```
var completeList = (presentEventList.Concat(absentEventList).ToArray());
return Json(completeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```